# Enable touch event on Drawer list plus container of drawer in Sliding Navigation, Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I have facing some issue, I have locked my navigation drawer in landscape mode, but when I touch in container layout then that is not work, because until drawer is not close control is not given to the container. 
So I want that at same time touch is enable to both the screens.